# What happens to very good answers from removed users? Do they get deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

What happens to very good answers from removed users? Do they get deleted?

In particular, I'm worried about user with over $100$ answers and over $10000$ rep.

I think they should be protected if not already.

Comment: Bill's user is not deleted. It's not even "Gone" anymore. It's his old username with his old account.

Comment: 2 accounts ? then he had the sum of those rep ?

Comment: @mick: those are not two accounts, just two names for the same account at different times. In any case, this question seems to be a general one, there is no reason to mention a particular user.

Comment: Related: [Browsing the answers by deleted users](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12256/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When an account is deleted, [all negatively scored posts are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account#comment393128_7979).  However StackExchange employs only "soft deletion" which means that these posts still exist, they are just hidden to users without sufficient [*privileges*](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).  Such posts can be restored (if you can direct moderators or other sufficiently privileged users to their location for undeletion).

(The undeleted posts *are* anonymized, meaning that the original user name is no longer associated with them, but rather some `user#####`, reflecting the user ID of the account.  Though not quite as simple as before there are [ways to find such posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9395/8348).)